# Select rows from a table with unique values in a column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to select top 3 records sorted by date such that the records doesn't have same ID, for two(or more) records of same ID select the one which is latest. Table is like this:

```
ID  | Date                 | Value
1   | 2013-04-29T16:27:20  | value1
2   | 2013-04-29T19:46:25  | value2
2   | 2013-04-30T16:50:30  | value3
3   | 2013-04-30T16:40:30  | value4
1   | 2013-04-30T17:50:30  | value5
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
ID  | Date                 | Value
1   | 2013-04-30T17:50:30  | value5
2   | 2013-04-30T16:50:30  | value3
3   | 2013-04-30T16:40:30  | value4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can implement [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the result:

```
select id, date, value
from 
(
  select id, date, value,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) seq
  from yourtable
) d
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6d97/1).

Or you could use a subquery with an aggregate function to return the `id` with the most recent date:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.value
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select id, max(date) date
  from yourtable
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.date = t2.date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6d97/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can You please explain how partition by and OVER works in this query

Comment: @JackDaniels The `row_number() over()` applies a partition to the data, so this is saying that you want an incremented number that increases for each id based on the date in descending order. If you had two columns that could be identical for your data, then you could partition it by the two columns.  See this MSDN link -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Date, t.Value
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Date, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM table_name
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1
```